# In the HHL algorithm, how large should the eigenvalue estimation register be?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

In the HHL algorithm, we need to estimate the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$. The result is stored in a register with $l$ qubits. Let $T = 2^l$. $T$ cannot be too small, otherwise the result would have a large error. How large should $T$ be?

The [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3171.pdf) (p. 11) states: we make the assumption that $\delta \leq T/10$. Here $\delta = \lambda_jt_0 - 2\pi k$, $\lambda_j$ is any eigenvalue of $A$, $t_0$ is another parameter to be chosen, and $k$ is an integer that ranges from $0$ to $T - 1$. However, this means that $\delta$ may be anything between $\lambda_jt_0 - 2\pi T$ and $\lambda_jt_0$. How is it possible to guarantee that $\delta \leq T/10$?